# How to get client's ip from axis2 webservice request in java?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I want to verify client connected to my web service server (I using jboss 7 to deploy my server). So I need to get client's ip from their request. How can I do it in java?

Comment: Client IP is not a reliable method for identifying a client.  Most clients are behind NAT firewalls, so many different clients will appear to have the same IP.

Comment: My server just run on local without internet so I think ip address is enough to verify a client. Tks

Answer (score 1):

I've just started learning WebServices.
Perhaps this line of code would help. Not very much sure about Axis2 but using some older versions of Axis, you may do like this.

```
MessageContext messageContext = MessageContext.getCurrentContext(); 
String ipAddress = messageContext.getStrProp(Constants.MC_REMOTE_ADDR);
```

there're few more Constants used to get client specific properties.
If necessary, you may wanna use some custom headers to fetch the properties.

Answer (score 1):

In Axis2, you get the remote (client) IP from the [`MessageContext`](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/apidocs/org/apache/axis2/context/MessageContext.html):

```
import org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext;
```

```
MessageContext mc = MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext();
String clientIP = (String) mc.getProperty(MessageContext.REMOTE_ADDR);
```

<sup>*Reference: [AXIS2-1610](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-1610): Need to get client IP address on server side*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I'm using axis2 1.5.3 , I read property "MessageContext.REMOTE_ADDR" but it returns ip address of my Jboss application server where deployed my axis2.war.

I put the code java in my class "MessageReceiverInOut" ,how i can obtain ip address of client which execute my web service Axis2 ?

A client, web app or not, call my url https://myDomain/axis2/services/MyService

MyService is an aar inside axis2.war

Thank a lots